# best way to test a mutex class?

Tags: php, mutex

I've create a Mutex class in PHP to try and solve a problem I am having but I don't know how to test it! Below is my code- what is the best way to force a situation where the locking would occur? I've tried running the code in two separate tabs in Firefox, but it is almost as if it just queues the requests and never fails because it can't get the mutex. 
Should I write a script that basically fires off a few requests to my page and make sure that one of them fails?
Any advice appreciated!

```
<?php
class MyCompany_EFInterface_Model_System_Mutex extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{                         
  var $lockName = "";
  var $fileName = null;
  var $file = null; 

  public function __construct($lockName) {
    $this->lockName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', '', $lockName);
    $this->getFileName();                         
  }

  public function __destruct() {
    $this->releaseLock();
  }

  public function getLock() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    return flock($this->file, LOCK_EX);    
  }

  public function releaseLock() {
    $success = flock($this->file, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($this->file);
    return $success;
  }

  public function getFileName() {
    $path = sys_get_temp_dir();
    if ( substr($path,-1) != DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ) $path.= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $this->fileName = $path . $this->lockName . ".lock";

    if ( ! $this->file = fopen($this->fileName, "c") ) {
      throw new Exception("Cannot create temporary lock file.");
    }                                                                                             
  }
}
```

Comment: Try having your script write lots of human-readable messages to a file, like a bunch of "Hello, world" with a unique identifier so you can see which script the message is coming from. Run them without the lock at first to verify that they clobber each other's messages in the file.

Comment: " I've tried running the code in two separate tabs in Firefox, but it is almost as if it just queues the requests" Not just 'almost', that is what is happening. Try a second browser (not FX, but Chrome, IE, etc.). To make testing easier, you could add some `sleep` statements.

Comment: @JoryGeerts- OK that makes sense then! I will try another browser and see how I go. And thanks for the tip on the `sleep` command- I was using this.